# Why is the use of calculus of variations so uncommon in "real" applications?

Tags: soft-question, calculus-of-variations, applications

I think everyone agrees that having a deep understanding of calculus is extremely helpful for many applied fields (physics, engineering, comp sci, etc.). But why does this not also hold for variational calculus?

There are a few fields in physics that I know of that use variational calculus as a starting point to derive a few important equations, but a deep understanding of variational calculus is considered to be unnecessary. For instance, "Lagrange equations of motions" in an advanced classical mechanics course are often derived without going into a more general theory on the idea of minimizing functionals.

Optimizing functionals *seems* to me to be a very powerful tool for things like nonlinear optimization, yet I find it to be extremely rare to come across *anything* that actually uses it practically. Is there a reason why this is the case? For example, maybe other techniques (genetic algorithms, monte-carlo simulations) are more practical?

Comment: If finite-dimensional nonlinear optimization is hard, its infinite-dimensional version is harder.

Comment: Isn't it true that you need to understand the calculus of variations in order to understand classical mechanics and much of physics? I had thought that the calculus of variations is very important in physics. For example the principle of least action is a major idea in physics, I had thought.

Comment: I want to add what @RodrigodeAzevedo said that even optimization in a "finite" set is hard enough. That is, if you want the calculation to end before Sun goes nova. In coding theoretical/combinatorial searches I've hear genetic algorithms being used, and colleagues and I have used simulated annealing. Monte Carlo is bread-and-butter.

Comment: Trajectory generation for autonomous vehicles discretizes infinite-dimensional problems and then uses finite-dimensional nonlinear optimization.